# 403 forbidden error when uploading to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403

I'm pretty new with AWS but im fairly certain I had my IAM user set up properly... are there any other permissions i need to add other than `AmazonS3FullAccess`? the name implies that it should be enough... either its a permissions issue or I messed up somewhere with my code.

I was trying to follow along with the guide at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node. any help would be appreciated. :)

Here is my relevant code:

```
//server side code
router.get('/sign-s3', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const { fileName, fileType } = req.query;
  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
      Bucket: S3BUCKET,
      Key: fileName,
      Expires: 60,
      ContentType: fileType,
      ACL: 'public-read'
  }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json(err)
      }
      res.json({
        signedRequest: data,
        url: `https://${S3BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    });
  });
});

//client side code
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    axios
        .get(`/api/bucket/sign-s3?fileName=${file.name}&fileType=${file.type}`)
        .then(signedResponse => {
            axios
            .put(signedResponse.data.signedRequest,file, {    
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              }
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("upload successful");
                props.addImages([signedResponse.data.url]);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

and a screenshot of my error:
[image: error message]

UPDATE:
  Removing the line `ACL: 'public-read'` from my sign route allows the upload to go through but then nobody can access the images. :P based on johns comments down below i assumed it was some kind of header issue so i added `'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'` header to my put request on the client side but its still giving me the same issue of an invalid signature

Comment: Could you post exact error message which you got?

Comment: added error message to OP

Comment: Are you uploading to an Amazon S3 bucket that belongs to the same account as the credentials being used? Was the content type provided as part of the HTML upload form? Was the upload performed within 60 seconds of the signed URL being created?

Comment: @John 
I created the bucket with my root user but the credentials are from an IAM user with full s3 access. content type was set to 'mulipart/form-data', and yes it was performed within 60 seconds.

Comment: The signed URL was generated for `ContentType: fileType`, so the provided content type must match whatever was in the `fileType` variable. Your code does not show where this value comes from. Was `fileType` equal to `multipart/form-data`? If you take the failed URL and paste it into a web browser you will receive a bigger error message. If it says `Invalid Signature`, then the uploaded file did not match the conditions of the signed URL.

Comment: the onChangeHandler is the on change event handler for the input element that I am using. fileType comes from event.target.files[0].type, which is passed into the sign request as a query param. i did change the content-type in the put request to match fileType but it still is giving me an error. i took your advice and opened the signed url in the browser; the error message is as follows: 
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Comment: @QamarStationwala any update on this? How did you fix it?

Comment: @caffeinescript im sorry i really dont remember what i did ._. i believe it was some kind of authentication issue but im not 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had updated my access keys but was using the old ones while creating the instance of S3

````
 s3 = new AWS.S3({
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,          // KEEP UPDATED ACCESS KEY   
      secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,  // KEEP UPDATED SECRET ACCESS KEY
    },```
````

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving same error with an IAM user with "AmazonS3FullAccess". What worked for me was adding this CORS configuration

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```