# Pre-signed S3 request returns PUT 403 (forbidden), despite setting Policy and Cors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following API:

```js
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { type NextApiRequest, type NextApiResponse } from "next";

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION + "",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID as string,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as string,
  },
});

export default async function signUrl(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { fileName, fileType } = req.body;

  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 3600,
    ContentType: fileType,
  };

  try {
    const command = new GetObjectCommand(s3Params);
    const url = await getSignedUrl(s3, command);
    res.status(200).json({ url });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).end();
  }
}
```

And this is how I use it on the frontend:

```js
function handleLoadImage() {
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "file";
  input.accept = "image/*";
  input.onchange = async () => {
    if (!input.files || !input.files[0]) return;
    const file = input.files[0];

    const response = await fetch("/api/signUrl", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ fileName: file.name, fileType: file.type }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Error generating signed URL");

    const { url } = await response.json();
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: file,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": file.type,
      },
    });
    
  };
  input.click();
}
```

But when I use it in the PUT request I get a 403 (forbidden) error.

I already reviewed all the solutions proposed in these posts and they are discarded:

- [Getting 403 (Forbidden) when uploading to S3 with a signed URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869962/getting-403-forbidden-when-uploading-to-s3-with-a-signed-url)
- [Amazon S3 bucket returning 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691286/amazon-s3-bucket-returning-403-forbidden)
- [403 forbidden error when uploading to S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61795753/403-forbidden-error-when-uploading-to-s3-bucket)

I have made sure that:

- do not use wildcards for content-type, and use the same one that returns the signature to upload it to S3.
- headers of the signed URL match that of the PUT request AFAICT.

Some propose to use

```js
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
   signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
```

I can't do that since I'm not using the whole SDK but just `@aws-sdk/client-s3`, and `S3Client` doesn't expose that property.

Comment: `      method: "PUT",` pretty sure that should be POST.  Although PUT would be a good semantic option, AWS APIs are not semantic in this sense.  Even the read-only requests are made using POST with request details in the Body.

Comment: I tried changing PUT to POST and still getting the same error. Do you know if there is something else I should change?

Comment: Your bucket policy is terrible.  That's saying any authenticated AWS user, not only those in your account, can put and get from your bucket.  You're using a presigned URL:  Bucket Policy and Public Settings are not important here - you're using credentials presumably from same account as bucket so default policy and all public access blocking is fine

Comment: One more thing I see: `const command = new GetObjectCommand(s3Params)` Why `GetObject`?  Aren't you trying to *Post* a new object?

Comment: Yes, the bucket policy is just for debugging and I'm not using this. As you said, I had to replace `import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";`. Do you want to put it as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const command = new GetObjectCommand(s3Params)
```

Since you're trying to *upload* an object to S3, this should be a `PutObjectCommand`